# What does the code in c++ mean?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I do not understand what is going on on variable k. For example I tried to put 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but k shows me 1.

```
    int a[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    int k = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        k += a[j] > a[j+1];
    }
    cout << k;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[j] > a[j+1]` produces a Boolean result (`false` or `true`). In an `int` context, `true` and `false` convert to `1` and `0` respectively.

So, this is roughly equivalent to:

```
for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    if (a[j] > a[j+1])
        ++k;
```

Comment: Code references a[5] for an array running from 0 to 4 - that's a problem.

Comment: ah yes, well spotted, tho it just means the last `>` is undefined. Sadly going 1 past the end of an array will rarely crash.

Answer (score 7):

k shows a value of one because you are accessing out of bounds array a.

When `j = 4`, `j+1` is `5` and so you are trying to access `a[5]` which is out of bound.
Hence it is incorrectly showing that `a[j] > a[j+1]` for one value. This is undefined behaviour.

Change your code to:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
  k += a[j] > a[j+1];
}
```

Now k will have a value of 0 if the input series is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

The loop iterates over the array `a`, comparing `a[0] > a[1]`, `a[1] > a[2]`, `a[2] > a[3]` etc..  When a boolean is added to an integer, it's first converted to 0 (if false) or 1 (if true).  So, `k` ends up being a count of the number of times an element if greater than the following element.